# Converter Float para Binário Python

Tags: python, conversão, float, decimal, binary

Estou estudando o padrão IEEE 754, e eu deveria criar um novo método com 16 bits. Esta função é para converter a mantissa que já está no formato 1,xxx*2^yyy

O que pode ter de errado neste código, que me parece certo mas está conversão não bate quando faço o caminho contrário.

```
def convert(num):
  final = []*16
  bits = []
  cont_exp = 0
  #define se o sinal é positivo ou negativo
  if(num>0):
    sinal = 0
  else:
    sinal = 1
    num = num*-1
  #caso maior que 2, dividir até conseguir o modelo 1,xxx*2^xx
  if (num>=2):
    while (num>=2):
      cont_exp += 1
      num = num/2
    #print("exp polarizado " + str(polariza(cont_exp)))
    cont_exp = converte(polariza(cont_exp))
    if num > 1:
      num = num - 1 
    num = num*2
    bits.append(str(1 if num > 1 else 0))
    while(num != 0):
      if num > 1:
        num = num - 1
        num = num*2
        bits.append(str(1 if num > 1 else 0))
      elif num < 1:
        num = num*2
        bits.append(str(1 if num > 1 else 0))
      else:
        num = num - 1
        bits.append(str(1 if num > 1 else 0))
    if len(bits) < 10:
      bits = normaliza(bits)
      final = str(sinal) + " " + str(cont_exp) + " " + ''.join(bits)
      return final
      #return final
    else:
      print ("overflow")
      #caso menor que 1, multiplicar até conseguir o modelo 1,xxx*2^xx
  elif (num < 1):
    while (num<1):
      cont_exp += 1
      num = num*2
    cont_exp = converte(polariza(cont_exp*-1))
    if num > 1:
      num = num - 1 
    num = num*2
    bits.append(str(1 if num > 1 else 0))
    while(num != 0):
      if num > 1:
        num = num - 1
        num = num*2
        bits.append(str(1 if num > 1 else 0))
      elif num < 1:
        num = num*2
        bits.append(str(1 if num > 1 else 0))
      else:
        num = num - 1
        bits.append(str(1 if num > 1 else 0))
    if len(bits) < 10:
      bits = normaliza(bits)
      final = str(sinal) + " " + str(cont_exp) + " " + ''.join(bits)
      return final
    else:
      print ("overflow")

      #caso no modelo 1,xxx*2^xx, converter
  else:
    cont_exp = converte(polariza(0))
    if num > 1:
      num = num - 1 
    num = num*2
    bits.append(str(1 if num > 1 else 0))
    while(num != 0):
      if num > 1:
        num = num - 1
        num = num*2
        bits.append(str(1 if num > 1 else 0))
      elif num < 1:
        num = num*2
        bits.append(str(1 if num > 1 else 0))
      else:
        num = num - 1
        bits.append(str(1 if num > 1 else 0))
    if len(bits) < 10:
      bits = normaliza(bits)
      final = str(sinal) + " " + str(cont_exp) + " " + ''.join(bits)
      return final
    else:
      print ("overflow")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá  - vamos por partes  -

primeiro

final = []*16

Não faz nada  - uma lista em Python não é um "array" - ela nãotem um número de slots fixos, e pode crescer dinamicamente com os métodos `append` e `extend`. Se você multiplicar uma lista vazia por 16, continua com uma lista vazia - nao com algo equivalente a um array com 16 posições.

Como você está usando sempre "append" esse problema, apesar de conceitual, não atrapalha no seu código, mas indica que você não experimentou as construções que está fazendo no modo interativo. O ambiente interativo é um dos pontos fortes do Python - vale muito a pena testar expressões e trechos de forma direta, e só daí escrever a expressão no programa - já fazemos isso com a certeza que aquele pedacinho vai funcionar.

```
 #caso maior que 2, dividir até conseguir o modelo 1,xxx*2^xx
 if (num>=2):
    while (num>=2):
      cont_exp += 1
      num = num/2
```

Ok - esse código normaliza o expoente - acho que entendi  - de qualquer forma, voce praticamente triplica o comprimento da sua função, sendo que o conteúdo das claúsulas  do if mais externo para números menores que 1, etc...é praticamente o mesmo você poderia colocar somente esse trecho no if mais externo, em vez de fazer a função 3 vezes maior com código repetido - isso induz mesmo a erros - volto a esse if mais externo mais abaixo.

Você não coloca na sua pergunta, nem coloca o que a função `polariza` faz - mas como ela so trabalha no expoente, vamos em frente ...

```
if num > 1:
  num = num - 1 
num = num*2
bits.append(str(1 if num > 1 else 0))
while(num != 0):
  if num > 1:
    num = num - 1
    num = num*2
    bits.append(str(1 if num > 1 else 0))
  elif num < 1:
    num = num*2
    bits.append(str(1 if num > 1 else 0))
  else:
    num = num - 1
    bits.append(str(1 if num > 1 else 0))
```

Esse trecho do códogo está esquisito por alguns motivos-  bom, dá pra entender que você quer testar o bit mais significativo sempre, e concatenar o valor do mesmo na sua cadeia de bits.

Mas o teste está estranho: se o número for um múltiplo de qualquer potencia de 2 maior que uma certa, o seu "num" vai chegar em zero antes de você ter todos os bits - e aí você vai precisar usar um pedação de código abaixo para tentar resolver isso.

outra: você já faz o teste `if num > 1:` - não tem que testar novamente ao faer o `bits.append` - em cada append, bastaria fazer `bits.append("1")` ou bits.append("0")  (também se você já sabe que quer colcocar as strings "1" e "0", não há necessidade de escrever um inteiro e chamar "str", pode escrever a string `"1"` direto).

Outra coisa estranha é seu "if" ter três cláusulas - ou o número é maior ou igual a 1 ou é menor que 1 - no primeiro caso, o bit que você quer tem valor "1". Não precisa de um caso especial quando o número for exatamente "1" -note que mesmo com as outras observações que já fiz, no caso do número ser exatamente "1", (num - 1) * 2 continua sendo "0", a multiplicação a mais não vai alterar em nada o seu resultado (e nesse nível de código, você não deve estar se preocupando com performance - você está operando de 4 a 5 ordens de grandeza menos eficiente do que poderia se performance importasse aqui - parte disso por estar usando uma linguagem de muito alto nível como Python, parte por conta do aproach que você escolheu)

Outra parte estranha nesse código é você ter uma cláusula "if" com código igual ao que vai dentro do `while` fora do while, antes do bloco - código duplicado de forma desnecessária.

Em vez disso, se você já sabe que quer extrair os 16 bits mais significativos, conte até 16, e simplesmente anote os bits que vão se tornando mais signigicativos - vou quebrar em uma funçãozinha menor, que já recebe o número com expoente normalizado:

```
def get_most_significant_bits(num, bits=16):
    result = []
    for i in range(bits):
        result.append("1" if num >= 1 else "0")
        if num >= 1:
            num -= 1
        num *= 2
    return result
```

desta forma, respondo às observações acima.
Agora continuando o seu código:

```
 if len(bits) < 10:
     bits = normaliza(bits)
     final = str(sinal) + " " + str(cont_exp) + " " + ''.join(bits)
     return final
 else:
     print ("overflow")
```

Não entendi por que você compara o `len(bits)` com 10 - não queria extrair 16 bits da mantissa²
Ai - de novo você não coloca a função `normaliza` - estou supondo que ela adiciona "0"s na string de bits até chegar ao comprimento de 10 dígitos.
Apesar das observações todas acima, o codigo parece estar certo até aqui  - então, o seu erro pode estar justamente na função "normaliza".

Outra coisa, a formatação de strings: Python é uma linguagem extremamente versátil para trabalhar com strings, mantendo a legibilidade - e isso de abrir e fechar aspas com um único espaço e usar "+" e conversões explícitas para `str` absolutamente não é necessário - 
Se você estiver usando a versão 3.6 ou posterior, pode criar o mesmo resultado com as "f-strings" - strings que permitem expressões de Python entre os sinais de `{ }` - sua formatação ficaria assim:

```
final = f"{sinal} {cont_exp} {''.join(bits)}"
```

Em Python 3.5 ou abaixo, poderia usar o método ".format":

```
final = "{} {} {}".format(sinal, cont_exp, "".join(bits))
```

Continuando - analizamos o primeiro terço da sua função, mas realemente, você tem mais dois blocos que são quase que exatamente iguais, mudando só o cálculo do exponte - 
então como já fiz acima, em que refatorei para a extressão da mantissa funcionar com números normalizados, vamos fazer o cálculo do expoente separado:

```
def get_exponent_and_normalized(num):
    # final number should be 0 < num < 2, and the corresponding FP exponent
    exponent = 0
    while True:
        if num < 1:
            exponent -= 1
            num *= 2
        elif num >= 2:
            exponent += 1
            num /= 2
        else:
            break
    return exponent, num
```

Note que estou usando a característica do Python de construção automática de tuplas com a "," no return, para, na prática, ter uma função que retorna dois valores.

Bom, temos agora uma forma genérica de pegar o expoente, e a mantissa - sem replicar o código em três condições de "if". Poderiamos ter uma funçãozinha similar apenas para pegar o sinal - mas nesse caso, ela seria igual o código que você já fez. Então, sem precisar de "polariza" e "normaliza" - dá pra fazer o código completo equivalente ao seu com:

```
def convert(num):
    if(num>0):
        sinal = 0
    else:
        sinal = 1
        num = num*-1
    cont_exp, normalized_num = get_exponent_and_normalized(num)
    bits = get_most_significant_bits(normalized_num)
    final = final = "{} {} {}".format(sinal, cont_exp, "".join(bits)) 
    return final


def get_most_significant_bits(num, bits=16):
    result = []
    for i in range(bits):
        result.append("1" if num >= 1 else "0")
        if num >= 1:
            num -= 1
        num *= 2
    return result

def get_exponent_and_normalized(num):
    # final number should be 0 < num < 2, and the corresponding FP exponent
    exponent = 0
    while True:
        if num < 1:
            exponent -= 1
            num *= 2
        elif num >= 2:
            exponent += 1
            num /= 2
        else:
            break
    return exponent, num
```

então  - o código ficou bem modular, mais fácil de verificar - e, está funcionando com os exemplos que testei aqui:

Infelizmente, apesar de dissecar com cuidado, não consegui achar o "ponto" em que seu código da erro. Pode ser na função "normaliza". Ou pode ser algo difícil de achar por conta do seu código ter bastante duplicação desnecessária - por isso que sempre evitamos duplicar código.
Sempre que você tiver programando e achar uqe precisa escrever um trecho - nem precisa ser grande - de código parecido, veja se não tem como fazer uma função separada.  Nesse caso nem foi necessário chamar a função mais de uma vez - mas vamos supor que não fosse tão trivial deixar esse trecho livre do "if" mais externo - dentro de cada parte do "if", todo o corpo do while e if interno seriam trocados por uma única linha chamando a função externa.

## Outra abordagem

Em geral, quando queremos "dissecar" um número em ponto flutuante, não ficamos fazendo várias operações de ponto flutuante com o mesmo - o ideal. é tratar um nḿero em FP como o que ele é: uma estrutura binária com um bits com papeís bem específicos .

Com os operadores para bits `&` ("and binário") e `>>`  e `<<` - shift left e shift right, conseguimos extrais os bits exatos  de um IEE 754 usando máscaras de bits - Em Python você pode usar um truque com o módulo "struct" para obter um número "unteiro" de 64 bits que seja a cópia binária de um número em ponto flutuante - para isso, você "codifica" o número em ponto flutuante, e a partir objeto bytes criado, "decodifica" um numero sem sinal de 64 bit inteiro. Nesse último, os operadores acima podem ser usados sem efeitos colaterais:

```
import struct
num = 2.125
string = struct.pack('<d', num)
integer = struct.unpack('<Q', string)[0]
```

Aqu tem um exemplo de como "traduzir" um float64 para um uint64 em Python - a partir daí você pode usar os operadores de manipulação de bit acima para extrair os campos binários do número. Daí é só ver na especificação e ver que o float tem 1 bit de sinal, 10 bits de expoente e 53 bits significativos.

Já que você está investigando e aprendendo - essa abordagem é bem legal também,e você poderá comparar as duas formas.